# Xcode design each screen sizewithout constraints

Tags: iphone, xcode, size, screen, constants

I've been using the constraints for all objects to be aligned with each of the different screen sizes, but I want to manually set each one.

How can I manually adjust the size and location of objects on each screen size?

Answer (score 0):

You can create storyboards for different sizes and load them; you can also set outlets for those constraints and set their constants. 
Nevertheless, I would advise you to keep them all in one storyboard and try to adapt the autolayout to make it work for every size.

Tip: add a another navigation tab and select preview mode on this one (on storyboard). This way you will be able to see how the constraints behave in different sizes.